# Is Acts_as_list's 'last?' method not working as intended or am i making a mistake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-list

So I am using acts_as_list in my current rails project. And I run into the following odd behavior:

When i remove an item from the list (item.remove_from_list) it correctly sets the position column of this item to *nil* and updates the position values of the other list items.

However, when I call last? on the "last" item in the list (e.g. the one with the highest position number) it returns false. In fact, every item in the list will return false to the last? method. I suddenly seem to have lost my last? item!

What's going wrong here?

Kind regards,
Erwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In acts_as_list, the `last?` method is added to each ActiveRecord instance:

```
# Return +true+ if this object is the last in the list.
def last?
  return false unless in_list?
  self.send(position_column) == bottom_position_in_list
end
```

First it checks if the object is in the list. Here's the method:

```
# Test if this record is in a list
def in_list?
  !send(position_column).nil?
end
```

So I would check the position_column of the object you believe to be last in the list to see if it is non-nil. Do this before and after you remove an object from the list.

Comment: I understand this and also checked the code. However its not working as expected: I have the 3 objects with positions 1, 2 and nil. The 3rd object had its position column reverted to nil by calling remove_from_list. I would expect the 2nd object to return true when I call last? on it. However, it returns false. Last? returns false on all three objects..

Comment: Yes, last? Returns false. That was in your question. The next step is going deeper in the code to find out why. What does in_list? return? What is the value of bottom_position_in_list?

Comment: Working my way back into the code brought to light an error for me. Thx for your help Mark